# "Orthogonal" or "mutually exclusive" coloring for a plot

Tags: data-visualization

I have a bar graph where the bars are colored according to chemical composition: Say atoms A, B, and C are interesting. I am currently mapping (A,B,C) composition, normalized, to (R,G,B) color as way to color each bar on the graph. Unfortunately, I have found that this leads to a rather ugly result, as most compounds fall at the extremes of the scale. I am looking for an alternative to the RGB mapping. I considered rotating in hue, but this leads to only limited possibilities, and none of them so far look very nice.

Is there a good way to choose three colors that look "different enough" to be used this way? Colorblind-friendly is a bonus.

Comment: You may have to resort to picking individual colors that make intuitive sense. In "additive" RGB system (as on screen or in theater lighting) R + G = Yellow. which is counterintuitive. Also, R+G+B = White. (Rest is OK intuitively, G + B = Cyan, R + B = Magenta.)  None of this is as in elementary school art class (mixing colors). Or as in color printing, a "subtractive" system based on Yellow, Magenta, Cyan ink subtracting from white of paper below. // In R, you might investigate `hsv` or color pallets instead of `rgb`. (But in `hsv`,  R at one  end and Magenta at other look almost the same.

Comment: The website colorbrewer2.org is intriguing and invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

[This Lancet paper](https://www.thelancet.com/action/showPdf?pii=S0140-6736%2818%2931194-2) using a 3-value coloring scheme based on CMY that might fit your needs. That is, it has distinct colors at the extremities and a paint-like blending logic for in-between colors. The graphic had a positive reception in the dataviz community, which is an indicator it also meets the "looks nice" objective.

(Possibly you meant something entirely different -- in which case, please elaborate your question.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some text to this to explicate your answer?